# How to send zip code as text within the searchbox which is within a iframe as per the website?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriver, webdriverwait

[image: HTML iframe code]

I am working on web automation with Selenium and I am having trouble entering the correct frame on the Dollar Tree website to search for store locations within a certain zip code. This is what I have so far;

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.dollartree.com/custserv/custserv.jsp?pageName=StoreLocations')

driver.switch_to_frame("Dealer locator")
time.sleep(2)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("inputaddress")
time.sleep(2)
elem.send_keys(zipcode)
```

I am unsure if changing the frame is necessary but I've tried

```
driver.find_element_by_id
driver.find_element_by_class_name
driver.find_element_by_xpath
```

and all of these give me the same error

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: To help you out share your html code for iframe in text format. Also [check this out](https://www.guru99.com/handling-iframes-selenium.html)

Comment: @theGuy added the iframe HTML code above

Comment: that's an empty iframe, there are no elements inside it. Also, please don't post images or screenshots. Code should be posted in text format so that we can help you more effectively

Comment: ok my bad, I figured it out. I needed to select the frame by its index (1) meaning that it was the second frame in the code

Comment: I'm glad that it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to send a character sequence to the *search box* just under the element with text as **Find A Store** you need to switch to the desired *iframe* inducing *WebDriverWait* and then again induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.dollartree.com/custserv/custserv.jsp?pageName=StoreLocations")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src='//hosted.where2getit.com/dollartree/']")))
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.addressentry#inputaddress")))
  element.click()
  element.clear()
  element.send_keys("799003")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: dollar_tree]